# How to make my normal account can execute `sudo`?

Tags: freebsd, sudo, accounts

I installed bare-bone FreeBSD, and added a new user. And added `sudo` package with command `pkg_add -r sudo`.
When I logged into the box with new user account, it cannot run sudo command. What procedure is required to do this?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adjust your sudo configuration ([sample.sudoers](http://www.gratisoft.us/sudo/sample.sudoers)) using visudo.

Perhaps you what something like this.

```
username    ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Answer (score 1):

In Linux you should add it to sudoers group. It should be similar in FreeBSD case